# What is the best way to store passwords and IDs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, security, url, passwords

I have a weather app that sends a request to an API service. The URL requires a parameter of `id="e4adadfare33"` so the API knows you're a user.

So far I'm storing that ID in plain text in my JavaScript file; however, I would like to make it more secure. And at the same time being able to send it as part of the URL.

What is the best way to do this in plain JavaScript.

Here's what the URL looks like:

```
http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1
```

Comment: There's no best way to store credentials at client-side. Use server to store credentials.

Comment: Why whould you use JS to save plain text ? Why do you use JS as a Database? Thats not the purpose of JS :D .. Use a database!

Comment: If you want to save money with a server-side solution (VPS, Etc).  Use a serverless approach like AWS lambda (With Nodejs) + API Gateway and execute the necessary request to `openweathermap` from it.  This way, the credential is safe! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your app is stateless, so you don't have sessions. In this scenario I really recommend you to use [JWT](https://jwt.io/) (Json Web Token), it's a really secure way for handling stateless authentication. You can store it wherever you want in the client side, just add it an expiration time, so you force it to be renewed each certain amount of time. For me, this is one of the best approaches.

Comment: No, the best approach is a server-side solution.

Comment: Click the link please, it's actually a server side solution